# Making extensible Grails applications

Tags: grails

Is there a way to make a Grails application extensible without giving out the source code to the application? The idea being that I want end users to be able to add functionality through custom made modules.

I found [this](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/hot-pluggable-extensions-in-grails-adding-and-changing-your-application-behaviour-on-the-fly/), but near the bottom it says:

> It is still unclear to me how an extension could add a plugin it needs or modify the Spring or ApplicationContext on the fly without a restart. The Grails roadmap suggests that there would be a hot-deployable plugin infrastructure in place soon, which might solve this question.

The closest thing I found on the [Grails Roadmap](http://www.grails.org/Roadmap) is this (as a "theme" for Grails 2.0):

> Take modular development with plugins to the next level by allowing modular deployment with OSGi

Would this be what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Binary Artifacts plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/binary-artifacts), which allows you to create artifacts without distributing the source code. If you create a combination of interfaces, extension points, and documentation then you should be able to let others use and extend your functionality without distributing your code.

Comment: So basically my application can act as a Grails plugin?

Comment: No, but it could be a small container for a plugin that has the functionality. Or the application could be created by your users, where they install your plugin and extend it.

Comment: The second thing you said is what I meant by "Grails plugin." That idea of a container is really cool too.